# why this extra "?_=1579068576376" is getting added to the URL '/api/customers' for my API request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I am making a request to api '/api/customers'
 but when I am checking the headers of network tab I see the url as
'http://localhost:56912/api/customers?_=1579068576376'

Not able to understand from where this extra value'?_=1579068576376' is coming

Below is the jquery code:

```js
//#customers is the id of table and I am using datatable plug in over it

$("#customers").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/customers",
                dataSrc: "",
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "name",
                        render: function (data, type, customer) {
                            return "<a href='Customers/Edit" + customer.id + "'>" + customer.name + "'</a>'"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<button  class='btn-link js-delete' data-customer-id="+ data+">Delete</button>"
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
        });
```

Below is the api I am trying to call:

```cs
public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> GetCustomers()
{
    return _context.Customers.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Customers,CustomerDto>);
}
//Context is an instance of db from entity framework
```

Comment: How can we check if you will not share the code with us?

Comment: It is called a "cache breaker": by adding a *timestamp* a new resource URL is generated and the browser cannot cache the resource (regardless of if it would/could - using appropriate cache-contol headers is often better). It is added *by code*, likely on the *request* or *URL generation*. The question does not provide enough details to answer *from where* it comes from. Start by looking at the *original HTML*; is it from the back-end or added by jQuery (etc. etc. work to narrow down the origin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a timestamp-ish thing, the milliseconds elapsed from `01.01.1970 00:00:00` to a specific point in time. Much like a UNIX timestamp, but with a greater precision.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ljUKp): It shows that the timestamp is `1/15/2020 6:09:36 AM (UTC)`.

Presumably this is the current timestamp for cache bursting (see the answer of Athanasios Kataras). Actually I did not find any source that confirms that this is added by ASP.NET MVC.

#### Edit

You are using the *DataTable* jQuery plugin with the `ajax` option which

> is passed to jQuery.ajax [[see here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object)]

In `jQuery.ajax` in turn

> [Disabling caching] works by appending `_={timestamp}` to the GET parameters. [[see the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) under the cache parameter]

This would explain the timestamp being added, albeit I don't quite understand *why* caching is disabled, for the default value should be `true` (i.e. caching is **enabled**) according to the jQuery documentation.

#### Edit 2

> Because DataTables sets the jQuery anti-cache parameter. [[see here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14471/cache-control#Comment_45854)]

Answer (score 3):

It's a timestamp(usually) or another unique number for browser cache busting.

> Cache busting solves the browser caching issue by using a unique file version identifier to tell the browser that a new version of the file is available. Therefore the browser doesn’t retrieve the old file from cache but rather makes a request to the origin server for the new file.

It effectively makes sure that when you have a get request, the browser will not consider it cached.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.It was due to the default value of caching being false. I have added a parameter, cache:true and the issue was resolved.
 $("#customers").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/customers",
                dataSrc: "",
                cache: true,
                columns:.....
...